# Receiving undefined from input property

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, parent-child

Ok so I'm trying to receive data from another component by calling the selector on the html file of the parent component like this:

`<app-graphs [module]="module" hidden></app-graphs>`

and in the child component i added the input property like this:

`@Input() module: Module = new Module({});`

but in the ngOnInit of the child component when i log the contents of the module i received from input it's always null/undefined. I put another console.log in the ngOnChanges and when i went back to the previous page it actually logged the content i was expecting. So it looks like its not loaded when i first try to use it. Can someone help me with this? It's not trowing any errors or anything, and the folders of the two components are in the same folder. I have no idea what to do

I'm on angular 13 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this code you are trying to keep a default value for the input, But default value only comes into picture if parent component doesn't pass any value for property. Here parent component is initially passing the value undefined which overrides the default value.

To solve you have to do one of these:-

1. Initialize this component only when data is present.
2. Do your logic in ngOnChanges of child component so when value is available and you receive the change, you are able to perform your logic.